# Why is ojdbc14.jar not supporting shutdown and startup , they were supported in version 5 and 6

Tags: oracle

```
ocon.shutdown(OracleConnection.DatabaseShutdownMode.IMMEDIATE);
```

This line is giving compilation error. I am using **ojdbc14.jar**. It was supported in **ojdb5.jar**.

Comment: `ojdbc14.jar` is completely outdated. It is intended to be used with Java **1.4**

Answer (score 0):

Oracle's naming is confusing (though somewhat influenced by Java): ojdbc14.jar is older than ojdbc5.jar.

- ojdbc14.jar for Java 1.4 (not supported anymore)
- ojdbc5.jar for Java 5
- ojdbc6.jar for Java 6
- ojdbc7.jar for Java 7 and 8